# Angular cli ChromeHeadless karma still open a browser

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular-test

I want to use ChromeHeadless with karma. My config is:

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

module.exports = function( config ) {
  config.set({
    basePath                : '',
    frameworks              : ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins                 : [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    angularCli              : {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters               : ['progress'],
    autoWatch               : false,
    browsers: [
      'ChromeHeadless',
    ],
    singleRun               : true
  });
};
```

When I run ng test I still need to open the browser. Here is what I'm getting from karma console:

> Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/

Answer (score 6):

Try to add this property to your `karma.conf.js`. [`Reference`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md)

```
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadless: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--headless',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use Puppeteer with Karma, you should be able to remove your `karma-chrome-launcher` from the plugins array as Puppeteer is supposed to handle everything itself, probably the plugin causes the unexpected behavior!

Comment: When I remove it I'm getting Cannot load browser "ChromeHeadless": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?